# Why my central diagonal image's border is darker on the bottom edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

Why my image border is darker on the bottom edge? This is the [Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-cdn-f6p9h)

In the following image, which provides a zoom on it, you can open a software like GIMP, then you can zoom to check more explicitly the values' difference:
[image: Show image issue]

I'm stuck with this problem, I don't know how the image has this behaviour, so I need your help.

Below the code snippet:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from "./styles.module.css"

export default class Homepage extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div className={style.component} >
    <div className={style.component} >
    {

     /*<div className={style.top_page}/>*/
    }
     <div className={style.top_image_container}>
       <div className={style.image_left}>
         <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/10/800/800.jpg"/>
       </div>
       <div className={style.diagonal_image}>
          
         <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/tomo00/tomo001605/tomo00160500403/56812872-wallpaper-material-check-plaid-cross-checkered-diamond-diamond-diamond-triangle-square-two-color-squ.jpg"/>
       </div>
         <div className={style.image_right}>
         <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/12/800/800.jpg"/>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

```css
.component{
 width: 100vw;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background: #00cdd7;
 background:white;
 color:white;
 font-size:5em;
 font-weight: bold;
}


.top_image_container{
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100vw;
  height:40vh;
  background:yellow;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start; 
}

img{
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image_left img{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute; 
  top: 0%; 
  left: 0%;
}

.image_right img{
 width:50%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute; 
  top: 0%; 
  right: 0%;
}

.diagonal_image{
 transform: scale(.9999);
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
  height:40vh;
  width:100%;  
  background:orange;
  top: 50%; right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
  clip-path:polygon(42.5% 0, 100% 0, 57.5% 100%, 0 100%)
}

.diagonal_image img { 
  position:relative; 
  z-index:100;
  height:180%; 
  width:100%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you call a "zoom on it" here? Browser's zoom? This browser zoom is the only way for me to reproduce your issue, and it's simply antialiasing + clipping that never worked well together.

Comment: @Kaiido yeah thanks for asking. So I meant I have made a screenshot of my screen then zoom on GIMP with its powerful zoom's feature to see if effectively the pixels was of different colors and yes, they was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a rendring issue related to the `clip-path`. You can fix it by adding an extra pixel to the element where you are applying the `clip-path`

Instead of `height:40vh` make it `height:calc(100% + 1px)`

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a dark backgroundColor to your `.component` style:

```
background: #00cdd7;
```

If the image you are displaying has transparency this would show through and cause that extra dark line at the bottom.